# How to fill a text field with an attribute using jQuery (Rails)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models: Post and Tag. The Post model has an `attr_accessor` called `:tag_name` and the Tag model has an attribute called `:name`.

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.cktext_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_name %>
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_name, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' ' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the output of the field:

```
<input data-autocomplete="/posts/autocomplete_tag_name" data-delimiter=" " id="post_tag_name" name="post[tag_name]" size="30" type="text">
```

I want the user to see the name of the tags as soon as they enter the show view.

Any suggestions of how to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

I tried putting this at the end of the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#post_tag_name').val($('#post_tag_name').val() + <%= render @post.tags %>);
</script>
```

But nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#post_tag_name').attr('value', '<%= render @post.tags %>');
```